# How to add Google Apps to Android TV VM?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv

I've setup an Android TV virtual machine using Android Studio but when I launch it there aren't apps installed.

I'd need to have access to the Google Apps for testing purpose and I can't find a way to install them inside the VM.

How can I do?

Comment: You can sideload apps through adb. The command is `adb install <path to apk>`

Comment: I think I can't sideload Google Apps... they usually need to be flashed along with some system files.

Comment: Which apps are we talking about here? If you can find the apk for it, you should be able to sideload it.

Comment: I'm talking about the Google Apps, the pack of apps provided by Google to any manufacture which want to include Google Play and all the Google apps in their OS

Comment: Those don't have a tv version. I suggest you look for the Play Store & Google Play service apk **for TV/leanback** and sideload those. Then you should be able to install more applications through the actual play store.